# Why are angles $\alpha_0$ and $\alpha_2$ equal?

Tags: geometry

Can someone please tell me what rule in geometry would show why angles  $\alpha_0$ and  $\alpha_2$ are equal?  I can see that angles a0 and a1 are equal because the red line is acting as a transversal line.  But I'm stumped as to what rule proves  $\alpha_0$0 is equal to  $\alpha_2$.

[image]

Comment: Because they are acute angles with perpendicular sides.

Comment: I hear what you are saying but I can't really visualize it.  which line is perpendicular to the other?

Comment: The sides in red are, and the pink side of $\alpha_0$  is perpendicular to the blue side of $\alpha_2$.

Comment: The unlabelled angle in the upper right triangle has measure $90^\circ-\alpha_1$, it also has measure $90^\circ-\alpha_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a longer walk through would be helpful, though the comments contain a good answer already.

You already know that $\alpha_0 = \alpha_1.$ So let's show that $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2$ and call it a day. If we think about the half circle of which $\alpha_1$ is a part, we know the angles here must add up to $180^\circ$ (or $\pi$ radians). We also know that the rightmost angle here must have size $90^\circ- \alpha_2,$ because it's part of a right triangle with $\alpha_2.$

Symbolically we have:

$$\alpha_1 + 90^\circ + (90^\circ - \alpha_2) = 180^\circ$$

or

$$\alpha_1 - \alpha_2 = 0$$

Which is exactly what we wanted. Hence $\alpha_0 = \alpha_1 = \alpha_2$

Answer (score 2):

[image: angled Z-angle]

Rotate the hinge through $90^\circ$ and you get angles on parallel lines.

Answer (score 2):

In the picture we see that the area with two pink and two red sides is a quadrilateral which means that the sum of all its angles is 360° .
Also two angles of the quadrilateral are 90° each i.e. their sum is 180° .
So the sum of rest of the two angles is also 180° .
Again the adjacent angle of alpha 2 is : 180° - alpha 2 (by linear pair of angles).
Now a1 + 180°-a2=180°
Hence a1 = a2.
(a here refers to alpha)

Comment: Quite ingenious! (+1)